# Hyperledger (fabric-blockchain) what can i do for such transaction to be carried out?

Tags: post, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

Can i check whether fabric (hyperledger-blockchain), are we allow to change the  letter 'a' and 'b' to something else like john, english: A, math:B, science: c, combine humanities:D, IT:A. Because right now, i'm trying to use (academic) blockchain to prevent forgery of certificate for my school project. If it is possible, may i know how it can be done? Is there any tutorial/ website that i can reference to?
Currently, i'm using this website as a reference(http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Setup/Chaincode-setup/) for init, invoke and query. I tried changing their example of letter 'a' and 'b' to suit my need. For instance, i had tried to init the args of John, English:A, Math:B and etc. It looks like the following below.

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "deploy",
  "params": {
    "type": 1,
    "chaincodeID":{
        "name": "mycc"
    },
    "ctorMsg": {
        "function":"init",
        "args":["John", "0", "English", "A", "Math", "B", "Science", "C", "Combined Humanities", "D", "IT", "B"]
    }
  },
  "id": 1
}
```

It seems ok as it returns

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": {
    "status": "OK",
    "message": "mycc"
  },
  "id": 1
}
```

But the moment i have tried and query English, Math, Science or combined humanities, it doesn't work. The following is my example for query.

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "query",
  "params": {
      "type": 1,
      "chaincodeID":{
          "name":"mycc"
      },
      "ctorMsg": {
         "function":"query",
         "args":["English"]
      }
  },
  "id": 5
}
```

The response given was this.

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "query",
  "params": {
      "type": 1,
      "chaincodeID":{
          "name":"mycc"
      },
      "ctorMsg": {
         "function":"query",
         "args":["English"]
      }
  },
  "id": 5
}
```

May i know what can i do for such transactions to be carried out? (Init, invoke and query to be carried out successfully)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose, You need to learn to write your own chaincode,

https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/learn-chaincode

and try running Asset management example,

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/master/examples/chaincode/go/asset_management/app

You can also try other examples available here,

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/master/examples/chaincode/go

However, Asset management example is perfect start for your scenario.